# 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I attempt to view any page, I get the error above.

Here's my layouts/application.html.erb code:

```
<body>
<%= link_to "Store Front", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="span4">
        </aside> 
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
        <aside class="span4">
          <%= render @cart %>
        </aside>  
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
```

the problem is causing by <%= render @cart %>.

Here's my application_controller :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  helper_method :current_order

  private

  def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
  end
end
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `before_filter :current_cart` in `application_controller`

And change `current_cart` with

```
def current_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  @cart
end
```

May this changes will work.

Comment: Perfect, you did it ! Thanks a lot